# How to add datatable inside another datatable in ICEfaces

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have two datatable the second one is depending one one. What I have done up to now is, when I clicked on a row of first table second table shows the corresponding value to the selected row.

What I want to do is make this second data table inside first and when I click on a row (first table) the second data table should appear from next row and also at the end of the second datatable the first datatable should continue.

I do not know how to do this, please help

```
<ice:dataTable id="fdf001" border="3" value="#{showDetails.showArr}" var="item">


    <ice:column id="column1">
    <ice:rowSelector  id="IdRowSelector"  
                            selectionListener="#{showDetails.rowSelectionEvent}"
                            value="#{item.selected}"  selectedClass="tableRowSelected" mouseOverClass="tableRowMouseOver">
    </ice:rowSelector>

        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Machine Name"></ice:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.machineName}"></ice:outputText>
    </ice:column>

    <ice:column id="column2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Status"></ice:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.status}"></ice:outputText>
    </ice:column>

    <ice:column id="column3">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Environment Client Database Instance"></ice:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.envClientDbInstance}"></ice:outputText>
    </ice:column>           

</ice:dataTable> 



<ice:dataTable id="subTable" border="2" value="#{showDetails.modArr}" var="sub">
    <ice:column id="sub1">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Artifact Id"/>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{sub.artifactId}"/>
    </ice:column>

    <ice:column id="sub2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Group Id"/>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{sub.groupId}"/>
    </ice:column>

    <ice:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:outputText style="font-size: 13px; color: blue" value="Version"/>
        </f:facet>
        <ice:outputText value="#{sub.version}"/>
    </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is not available in the standard data-table in icefaces. It is available with the enterprise component - **a rich datagrid**.

Probably you can switch to the datagrid for this.

Otherwise you surely can have an **expandable table** instead. You will find the 'why and  how' [here](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

Answer (score 0):

Well You can do. It is possible.
You Just need to have structure of class like :

```
class showDetails{

 List<Information> showArr; // also create setter/getter

}

class information{
  List<SubInfo> showSub;

}
```

Now what u need to do is just Create Data Table inside Column of Parent dataTable
and pass currentRow.showSub to sub DataTable.